# Highstock: How do i display the series name along the line

Tags: highcharts

Here is a sample fiddle (1) that shows the series name along the line body 
(Sessions, Users). How do I make similar label for a highstock chart?

(The label seems to be appearing due to the data module that does the csv processing)

(1) https://jsfiddle.net/4restw8a/9/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    chart: {
        scrollablePlotArea: {
            minWidth: 700
        }
    },

    data: {
        csvURL: 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/highcharts/highcharts/' +
            '057b672172ccc6c08fe7dbb27fc17ebca3f5b770/samples/data/analytics.csv',
        beforeParse: function (csv) {
            return csv.replace(/\n\n/g, '\n');
        }
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Daily sessions at www.highcharts.com'
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: Google Analytics'
    },

    xAxis: {
        tickInterval: 7 * 24 * 3600 * 1000, // one week
        tickWidth: 0,
        gridLineWidth: 1,
        labels: {
            align: 'left',
            x: 3,
            y: -3
        }
    },

    yAxis: [{ // left y axis
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        labels: {
            align: 'left',
            x: 3,
            y: 16,
            format: '{value:.,0f}'
        },
        showFirstLabel: false
    }, { // right y axis
        linkedTo: 0,
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        opposite: true,
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        labels: {
            align: 'right',
            x: -3,
            y: 16,
            format: '{value:.,0f}'
        },
        showFirstLabel: false
    }],

    legend: {
        align: 'left',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        borderWidth: 0
    },

    tooltip: {
        shared: true,
        crosshairs: true
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            cursor: 'pointer',
            point: {
                events: {
                    click: function (e) {
                        hs.htmlExpand(null, {
                            pageOrigin: {
                                x: e.pageX || e.clientX,
                                y: e.pageY || e.clientY
                            },
                            headingText: this.series.name,
                            maincontentText: Highcharts.dateFormat('%A, %b %e, %Y', this.x) + ':<br/> ' +
                                this.y + ' sessions',
                            width: 200
                        });
                    }
                }
            },
            marker: {
                lineWidth: 1
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'All sessions',
        lineWidth: 4,
        marker: {
            radius: 4
        }
    }, {
        name: 'New users'
    }]
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This comes from the series label module, which you can use by including `series-label.js`:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js"></script>
```

See [this JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/d0oaemvq/1/) of a Highstock chart with it included.

See [this API documentation](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/plotOptions.series.label) for its settings.

Comment: Thank You Halvor. And what format should the json be if I like the series name to come in along with the json response from the server? The series list is gonna be dynamic,

I am hoping there will be a centralized doc repo where all these hidden modules are documented.

Comment: The series `name` option is what is being shown. How do you process your JSON? You do something like `addSeries` at some point, or? If so, just provide a `name`.

Comment: I am assigning the series like so:
series: data

and if i have my data json file like below, it works:
[
  {
    "name": "Aermine",
    "data": [
      [
        1461276000000,
        5229
      ],
      [
        1470261600000,
        0
      ],
      [
        1470348000000,
        3094
      ]
    ]
  },